# Rake test does not run my controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Try to learn TDD and using railstutorial. But somehow bundle exec rake test does not run all of my controller tests. Below sharing my gem list, controller_test code and output of rake test, what am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance
**Here is my gem list**

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails'
  gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
  gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
  gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc
  gem 'tzinfo-data'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug', '3.4.0'
  gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace', '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

**Here is my controller_test**

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

**When I run bundle exec rake test** (Even if I got no about page seems like it just run 2 tests and not the third one and all of them pass.

```
Finished in 0.303118s, 6.5981 runs/s, 6.5981 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Can you please list the full error message that you get while running tests?

Comment: There is no error it says 2 runs, 2 assertions so it is running 2 test case I think but I got 3.
It should be running something else or I dont know why it is not running the third test.